# Hiding and showing span in HTML

Tags: javascript, jsp, html

I have a JSP page on which i have some `input submit` buttons. Now based on some values i get from an `AJAX` request i want to control the `display and hiding of these input buttons`. So i have created `spans` for each input. And based on the variable value i received from AJAX request i manipulate there display property. But i am not getting the results right.

here's my code:

```
<td style="width: 600px"><span id="startspan"><input name="start" value="startActivity" type="submit" id="startbuttonid"></span></td>
       <td style="width: 600px"><span id="holdspan"><input name="start" value="holdActivity" type="submit" id="holdbuttonid"></span></td>
       <td style="width: 600px"><span id="cancelspan"><input name="start" value="cancelActivity" type="submit" id="cancelbuttonid"></span></td>
       <td style="width: 600px"><span id="closespan"><input name="start" value="closeActivity" type="submit" id="closebuttonid"></span></td>
```

And my `java script` code where i am writing code for display or hiding them is ::

```
if(temp1[15]=="InProcess"){
        document.getElementById('startspan').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('holdspan').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('cancelspan').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('closespan').style.display = 'block';
    }
    if(temp1[15]=="New"){
        document.getElementById('startspan').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('holdspan').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('cancelspan').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('closespan').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

here based on variable `temp1[15]` value which i am receiving fine. I want to display or hide those input submit buttons. I am doing it the right way, like defining span or need some correction. Basically all those input buttons are inside a `dialog box <div>` which opens up only when a function is triggered inside which i have written my Hiding or showing span code(Written above). Need help. Thanks.

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle here and everything seem to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uGvam/

Answer (score 3):

The `display` property in CSS also determines whether it acts like a block (DIV, P, etc), or an inline element (span, b, etc), as well as its visibility.

For your spans you want to do this instead:

```
document.getElementById('span').style.display = 'inline';
```

If it was a DIV you would use `block`, and if it was an IMG you would use `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is working in the fiddle and not in your main code, I suspect that there might be an issue related to your code executing before the DOM is loaded (or the `dialog box <div>` is generated). You mention that you're using AJAX. Make sure that the code to show or hide the buttons is in the AJAX success callback.

Comment: If you could show your code with the AJAX method, that would be helpful.